# Write data in the db in a different way

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an app that I used to read data from an external device through bluetooth.

For example:

```
async setupNotifications1(device) {
    var timeagm = 0
 this.subscriptionMonitor1 = device.monitorCharacteristicForService(service,this.AccGyrMg, (error, characteristic) => {
    const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
            const [...acc] = [2,4,6].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));
            this.setState(state => ({acc,array_acc_sx: [...state.array_acc_sx,[timeagm , acc ]]
            }));
//...
}}
```

Then I pass this value of a function and I wrote these data in the db.

My data in the DB are like: (for example, these data change everytime, only the variable "time" is equal)

```
"AL": "[[0,[80,-685,-714]],[20,[80,-686,-712]],[40,[81,-687,-711]],[60,[81,-687,-712]],[80,[81,-686,-712]],[100,[80,-673,-713]]
```

*What I would to obtain is data like:*

```
"AL": [

[

0:80:-685:-714,

20:80:-686:-712,

40:81:-687:-711,

60:81:-687:-712,

80:81:-686:-712,
```

How can I do??

Also I have another problem, as you can see the first value is the time. At the moment I print all the values in a row, I would to separate values after 1000(time)

So for example:

```
"AL": [
    [
      "0:-35:-70:-1041",

      "20:-36:-69:-1041",

      "40:-35:-70:-1041",

      "60:-36:-69:-1040",

      "80:-36:-69:-1040",

      .......

      "1000:-36:-68:-1041"

    ],

    [

      "1020:-36:-68:-1044",

      "1040:-36:-68:-1043",

      "1060:-36:-68:-1045",

    ........
]
```

Thank a lot for your help!  if you want some clarification, I am at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
this.setState(state => ({acc,array_acc_sx: [...state.array_acc_sx,[timeagm , ...acc ].join(":")]
```